# How can I add the DateTimeOriginal property to a jpg using PEL (php exif library)

Tags: php, metadata, exif, pel

I have been working on storing metadata in images with varying success. I have been able to add most of the fields I need but have hit some inexplicable difficulties. This code works for the first 5 adds but the `DateTimeOriginal` is not being added. No errors pop up it just simply does not appear in the resulting metadata.

```
function setMetadata(PelIfd $ifd, array $tags)
{
  $ifd->addEntry(new PelEntryAscii(PelTag::XP_AUTHOR, $tags['Author']));
  $ifd->addEntry(new PelEntryAscii(PelTag::XP_COMMENT, $tags['Comments']));
  $ifd->addEntry(new PelEntryAscii(PelTag::XP_KEYWORDS, $tags['Keywords']));
  $ifd->addEntry(new PelEntryAscii(PelTag::XP_SUBJECT, $tags['Subject']));
  $ifd->addEntry(new PelEntryAscii(PelTag::XP_TITLE, $tags['Title']));
  $ifd->addEntry(new PelEntryTime(PelTag::DATE_TIME_ORIGINAL, $tags['DateTimeOriginal']));
}
```

Comment: what value is in the DateTimeOriginal? The docs indicate the timestamp should be a unix timestamp, e.g. a signed integer.

Comment: I tried entering an integer value with no effect

Comment: Figured it out. This is a great tool but extremely difficult to figure out.
 
$ex = new PelIfd(PelIfd::EXIF);
    $ifd->addSubIfd($ex);
    $ex->addEntry(new PelEntryTime(PelTag::DATE_TIME_ORIGINAL, $tags['DateTimeOriginal']));